How do I add Angular Material component using innerHTML?
I try to add Angular Material element using innerHTML.
It works but Angular Material Button looks very normal and disabled property binding has no effect.
Am i going in the wrong direction?
any advice?

component.ts
import { Component, AfterViewInit, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';

@Pipe({
    name: 'sanitizeHTML',
    standalone: true
})
export class SanitizeHTMLPipe implements PipeTransform {
    constructor(private _sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

    transform(html: any): SafeHtml {
        return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(html);
    }
}

@Component({
    selector: 'app-component',
    standalone: true,
    imports: [MatButtonModule],
    templateUrl: './component.html',
    styleUrl: './component.scss'
})
export class Component {
    isHeroDisabled = false;

    hero = '<button mat-flat-button color="primary" [disabled]="isHeroDisabled">Angular Button</button>';
}

component.html
<button 
    mat-flat-button 
    color="primary"
    (click)="isHeroDisabled=!isHeroDisabled">Enabled/Disabled
</button>

<div [innerHTML]="hero | sanitizeHTML"></div>


Why do you want to do it like this?

dynamic add more Angular Material Elements using @for loop

you can't add any angular components using innerHtml, they simply won't work.
but probably there is an alternative to innerHtml to achieve the same desired result. You should ask another question describing the actual challang you have and the goal you want to achieve.
